# Implement Delegate Method on NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I am attempting to implement a delegate method on `NSTextField` as described in [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1454/_index.html) from Apple. My goal is for the `NSTextField` to accept carriage returns and tabs. I have read elsewhere (including the linked article) that `NSTextView` is a better choice. However, I am working within a multiplatform framework that lacks support for `NSTextView`, and `NSTextField` will do the job if I can get it to accept carriage returns.

Based on the article, here is my code:

```objectivec
@interface MyTextFieldSubclass : NSTextField
{}
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector;
@end

@implementation MyTextFieldSubclass
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
   BOOL result = NO;

   if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:))
   {
      // new line action:
      // always insert a line-break character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
      [textView insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
      result = YES;
   }
   else if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:))
   {
      // tab action:
      // always insert a tab character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
      [textView insertTabIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
      result = YES;
   }

   return result;
}
@end
```

Additionally, in the Identity Inspector of the text field, I have changed the class name from the default `NSTextField` to my class name. However, when I run my program, the delegate method never gets called. Is there something else I have to do to set this up in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few parts of the documentation you linked which is pertinent that I think may have been neglected.

I've copied a few of the lines below:

> Should you decide to keep using NSTextField, allowing the tab key and/or allowing enter and return keys for line-breaks can be achieved by implementing the following **delegate** method:

> - (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector;

> Note: When implementing this **delegate** method in your **own object** you should set your object up as the "delegate" for this NSTextField.

I've bolded a few of the callouts which I think might have been missed.

This method is within the `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` protocol within NSControl.h. As such it should be implemented by a class which implements the `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` (i.e. `NSTextFieldDelegate`)

One common way of doing this is to have the ViewController "holding" the NSTextField be the `NSTextFieldDelegate`.

Here's a very simple example using the sample code from Apple you linked:

ViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ViewController : NSViewController <NSTextFieldDelegate>


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];

    // Update the view, if already loaded.
}

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {
    BOOL result = NO;
     
        if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:))
        {
            // new line action:
            // always insert a line-break character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
            [textView insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
            result = YES;
        }
        else if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:))
        {
            // tab action:
            // always insert a tab character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
            [textView insertTabIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
            result = YES;
        }
     
    return result;
}


@end
```

Then set your NSTextField's delegate to the ViewController

[image: Set_Text_Field_Delegate]

No need to add a custom subclass.

Alternatively you could probably make the custom text field subclass its own delegate. Something along these lines:

```
#import "MyTextFieldSubclass.h"

@interface MyTextFieldSubclass() <NSTextFieldDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyTextFieldSubclass

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    
    // Drawing code here.
}

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {
    BOOL result = NO;

       if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:))
       {
          // new line action:
          // always insert a line-break character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
          [textView insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
          result = YES;
       }
       else if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:))
       {
          // tab action:
          // always insert a tab character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
          [textView insertTabIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
          result = YES;
       }

       return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: I did eventually figure this out using the ViewController pattern you gave. I will mark this as an answer, and thank you. It might be helpful to include that in order to make the View Controller object available as a delegate target, you have to drag a view controller from the library palette to the left-hand column of the window and then change its class in the inspector. (That is, assume I know absolutely nothing about IB, which going into this project I was close to.)
Also, I did not include viewDidLoad or setRepresentedObject in my implementation, yet it appears to work. Problem?

Comment: @rpatters1 Glad the answer helped. When creating a new macOS app in Xcode it creates a default ViewController class which is what I used in the example here. viewDidLoad and setRepresentedObject are automatically added to this default class (which is why I left them in here) although it shouldn't change the functionality at all as you noted.

Comment: I'm working on a plugin for a host-app that provides cross-platform support for dialog boxes. Thus, my project had no View Controller at all until I added it.